# Different ways of calling functions C++

Tags: c++, function

I know this is a very basic question, but after a few google searches and clicking on multiple links, I still couldn't find an answer.

My question is what is the difference between the " . " and the " -> " in function calling in C++ language?

For example, I have a program with 2 different data structures.
Semaphore aaa;
List bbb;

To use a function on semaphore, I have to do aaa.P();
but on List, I have to do List->append(object);

I don't quite understand why Semaphore uses .P() whereas List uses ->append() 
when semaphore is just a data structure containing an integer and a list.

Comment: This is very probably a duplicate but searching for operator names is so painful >_<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.` operator when you're accessing members using the object itself, or a reference to the object.

```
struct Foo
{
  void bar() {}
};

Foo foo;
Foo& fooref = foo;

foo.bar();
fooref.bar();
```

Use the `->` operator when you're accessing a member via a pointer to the object. Continuing the above example

```
Foo *fooptr = &foo;

fooptr->bar();
(*fooptr).bar();  // same as preceding line
```

Answer (score 4):

#### On the surface:

`a.b` is used for accessing member `b` of object `a`.
`a->b` is defined to be eqivalent to `(*a).b` if `a` is a pointer type.

#### More info:

The `.` can't be overloaded, but `->` can be overloaded for classes (non-pointer types). The return value of the `->` operator is the result of applying the `->` operator until a pointer type is reached.

Note that this is **impossible** to do with a sequence of dereference-followed-by-member-access operations (try it and see), *even though* the `*` (dereference) operator is overloadable. This is because you need to "loop" over the result of evaluating the *return type* of `->` at *compile-time*, which is impossible to do manually. It's useful for making a proxy of an object that behaves like a pointer to the object.

Comment: +1 But perhaps you should have linked an example of `->` with smartpointers (the most famouse users of the `->` overload)

Answer (score 2):

In `Foo.Bar()`, `Foo` is an object of a class that has `Bar()`.

In `Foo->Bar()`, `Foo` is a *pointer* to an object that has `Bar()`.

It's not so much a matter of which class uses which operator, but which operator to use depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

`.` means access an item within the object (for both data *and* functions). `->` is the same but it uses a *pointer* to the object.

For example:

```
struct abc { int xyz; } a;
struct abc *pointer_to_a = &a;
a.xyz = 271828;                  // manipulates the object directly.
pointer_to_a->xyz = 314159;      // manipulates the object through a pointer.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others said, `foo->bar()` is the exact same thing as `(*foo).bar()`. It's just a shorthand and convenient notation. That is unless the `->` operator is overloaded for `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your original question is concerned, the reason for the difference is that Semaphore is a class type, and List is a pointer type. This is a fact about your particular program, not so much about the language. Most likely there are some typedefs making this structural feature of your program one that is not immediately obvious.